# List for each new instance of a class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# class Team.cs. When I create a team I fill the Event list by doing this:

```
team.Events = db.Events.Where(sc => sc.SchoolcupEvent == true).ToList();
```

It works fine if I only create one team but when I create a second team it looks like the Event list of the first team is empty again, does anyone know why this happens?

You can find the code of my teamcreate below.

Team.cs:

```
public class Team {

[Key]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "A name is required")]
public string TeamId { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Photo")]
public string Photo { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Logo")]
public string Logo { get; set; }


[Required(ErrorMessage = "A sports type is required")]
public string Sport { get; set; }

public int CoachId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("CoachId")]
public virtual Coach Coach { get; set; }
public string SchoolId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("SchoolId")]
public virtual School School { get; set; }

public double Score { get; set; }

public List<Event> Events { get; set; }


[Required(ErrorMessage="A gender category is required")]
public string Gender { get; set; }
```

}

Creation of team:

```
public ActionResult Create(Team team, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
  Coach loggedCoach = new DBUserFinder().getLoggedCoach();
  team.CoachId = loggedCoach.CoachId;
  team.SchoolId = loggedCoach.SchoolId;
  team.Events = db.Events.Where(sc => sc.SchoolcupEvent == true).ToList();
  ViewBag.Type = new SelectList(db.Sports, "SportName", "SportName");
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    int i = 0;
    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
    {
      if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
      {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var extention = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        var allowedExtensions = new[] { ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg" };
        if (allowedExtensions.Contains(extention))
        {
          fileName = team.TeamId.ToString();
          String fullPath = "";
          if (i == 0)
          {
            fullPath = fileName + " photo" + extention;
          }
          if (i == 1)
          {
            fullPath = fileName + " logo" + extention;
          }
          var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/IO/Team"), fullPath);
          file.SaveAs(path);
          if (i == 0)
          {
            team.Photo = "../../Content/Images/IO/Team/" + team.TeamId + " photo" + extention;
          }
          if (i == 1)
          {
            team.Logo = "../../Content/Images/IO/Team/" + team.TeamId + " logo" + extention;
          }
        }
        i++;
      }
    }
    db.Teams.Add(team);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the code for `Event` but it looks like you are modelling team to event as a one to many when it should be a many-to-many.

If you change you event class to the following, it will model it as a M2M.

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; } 

    public string EventName { get; set; }
    // .....all your other properties

    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }  // this along with the List<Event> property in Team will result in a M2M relationship
}
```

This should result in an `EventTeams` mapping table being created for you.  My migration file looks like this:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.EventTeams",
    c => new
        {
            Event_EventId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            Team_TeamId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Event_EventId, t.Team_TeamId })
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Events", t => t.Event_EventId, cascadeDelete: true)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Teams", t => t.Team_TeamId, cascadeDelete: true)
    .Index(t => t.Event_EventId)
    .Index(t => t.Team_TeamId);
```

Also, pop in `virtual` on your Team model to allow for lazy loading:

```
public virtual List<Event> Events { get; set; }
```

HTH